Movie about abusive man who was living with lot of women and children in the forest or something
A long time ago I saw one movie and have no idea how it is called. It was about some kind of community, sect (I guess it wasn't religious) or just strange lifestyle where one man was living with lot of women and children somewhere in the forest but he was cruel abusive etc and those women was so traumatized that couldn't leave that man until one outsider woman decided to intervene and help those women/children to leave that place. 
Then there was a trial, in that trial one of that man's daughter told how that man was teaching kids who aren't his eat under the table, how in the nights everyone had to dance naked around him etc and court put that man in the prison.
Before ending appears ending summary that few women couldn't leave that man and decided to move next to his prison or something like that. If you at least suspect what movie could it be plz tell, I'm searching for it for years 

How long ago was A long time ago? 5 years? 35 years?

The film Savage Messiah (2002), revolves around a commune out in the woods. Roch 'Moïse' Thériault (Luc Picard) is the leader of this commune where he lives with many women and many children. 
A social worker Paula Jackson (Polly Walker) becomes suspicious and later aware of goings on at the community that she finds (as do the community at large) abhorrent, after visiting this place and meeting with the leader and some of the residents. Paula’s intervention leads to an eventual trial.
Several abuses come to light around this time and at the trial including, certain children having to eat from the floor, sexual, physical and mental abuses.
At the films conclusion there is indeed a summary outline including certain wives who remain loyal and live near by.
This film is a dramatization of real life Roch Thériault, who was arrested in 1989.




We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed. You can explain how this moving matchs with questions.

Panther, maybe if the answer section had prompts where we could answer in specific sections it would be easier to provide a longer answer.

+1 for putting effort to add longer answer. I hope it is the movie question is asked about.

I changed the answer as I now understand the site rules better.
